# Count all eMails in my GMail-Account per GScript

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I have create a script which count all my eMails which are in my Gmail-Account.

My problem is: The script is running without any fault, but it stops without any memo by 686.

Why? Does anyone have an idea?

Greetings

```
function showEmailCount() {
  var myMe = Session.getActiveUser();
  GmailApp.sendEmail(myMe, "proAnzahlMeinereMails startet nun","");

  var count = getEmailCount();
  GmailApp.sendEmail(myMe,"Du hast " + count + " E-Mails in deinem Postfach.","");
}

function getEmailCount() {
  var emails = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(GmailApp.search("in:anywhere"));
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {
    count += emails[i].length;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

now I have changed the script and here I get the Info back "Exception: Argument max cannot exceed 500" - Surely there must be a way to count my e-mails?

```js
function countAllEmails() {
  let final = false;
  var count = 0;
  let start = 0;
  while (!final) {
    let threads = GmailApp.search('in:anywhere', start, 500)
    if(threads.length == 0){
      final = true;
      }
    var emails = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
    for (var i = 0; i < emails.length; i++){
      count += emails[i].length;
      }
    
    start = start + 500;
  }
  Logger.log("Number of emails in the inbox: " + count);
}
```